# compile typescript code to npm on Azure DevOps and add as dependency in angular project

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops

I have been tasked with something that is entirely outside of my knowledge. Using devops...

What I am asked to do is take a typescript library, 
compile it into an npm package, 
publish it to DevOps (as an artifact?) 
and pull it as a dependency to an angular project.

I have never worked with devops, and none of my colleagues have an idea how I can do this, which brings me to SO for help...

I have so far managed to get a pipeline to run npm install and npm build and made an access token. The problem I think I am having is that I cannot access the npm package from the server in my VSCode... It is telling me I do not have the right credentials... as it is giving me a E401 with unable to authenticate...

https://hatebin.com/pjntlhjocn

Edit: I have tried the steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page. the mention needing to use password and username with the PAT. but its not specified where...

Comment: You are not clear, did you succeed to package the typescript to npm package and publish it to Azure DevOps? when you got an error, when you try to run `npm install` in the angular project?

Comment: The project was uploaded as a typescript project to DevOps by my boss. I ran a build pipeline on it with first `npm install` followed by `npm publish` which made it appear in the artifacts. From there I need to download it as a dependency for angular

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar problem as you met: [code E401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958659/unable-to-authenticate-when-trying-to-connect-to-azure-devops-artifacts-feed-t).

It is possible that there's a mismatch in your `.npmrc` file which you can find the solution in above link.

If you have no idea about this `.npmrc` file, please check [Set up your client's npmrc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) for more information. This should be the information you are currently looking for。