# npm install unable to authenticate at incorrect url

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

When I run `npm install @types/js-cookie@^2.2.0` I get this error:

> npm install @types/js-cookie@^2.2.0
>
> npm ERR! code E401
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/"
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\A183540\Me\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-18T09_16_35_272Z-debug.log

I'm not sure why it's trying to access `https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/` as my `.npmrc` is this:

```
; begin auth token
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/registry/:username=me@megroup.com
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/registry/:_password="token"
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/registry/:email=me@Megroup.com
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/:username=me@megroup.com
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/:_password="token"
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/:email=me@megroup.com
//avdigitalweb.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MeDigital.NPM/npm/registry/:always-auth=true
; end auth token
```

I'm unsure where `https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/` is coming from so can't update it and also keep getting directed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958659/unable-to-authenticate-when-trying-to-connect-to-azure-devops-artifacts-feed-t) but I'm unable to install any packages, therefore can't install `vsts-npm-auth`. Is there any other way this can be resolved?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but both will get you the packages from 13.107.42.18

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958659/unable-to-authenticate-when-trying-to-connect-to-azure-devops-artifacts-feed-t

Comment: I looked at it but I'm unable to install `vsts-npm-auth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regenerated the AzureDevOps token.

Comment: how do you do that? did you replaced the old one in the pipeline?